# Can't connect to local MySQL server

Tags: server, python, 17.10, mysql, xampp

mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)") in Ubuntu 17.10

After I installed MySQL-python and XAMPP I wrote this code in PyCharm:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","yara","yara","yara")

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")

data = cursor.fetchone()

print "Database version : %s " % data

db.close()
```

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 is now EOL (July 19th), it's time to upgrade to 18.04 LTS

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [OperationalError: (2002, “Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)”)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18150858/711006)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that MySQL DB is working on your localhost and have actually that user? Are you able to login to SQL shell?

Edit:
I tested Python code and it actually working for me (with and without parameters='something', double and one quoted). I think that your DB is not working.

Did you start it? I'm not using XAMP (for me it is not recommended to use it in Linux). You can install MySQL Server(without XAMP) with `sudo apt install mysqlserver` command, start it with: `systemctl start mysql.service/ service mysql start` 
After that you can verify if daemon is running: `ps -ef | grep -i mysql` 
then you can try to log in: 
    mysql -u root -p

After that you can create DB and Table like this:

```
mysql> Create Database Dance;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,02 sec)

mysql> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> use Dance;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE cats
    -> (
    ->   id              INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, # Unique ID for the record
    ->   name            VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,                # Name of the cat
    ->   owner           VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,                # Owner of the cat
    ->   birth           DATE NOT NULL,                        # Birthday of the cat
    ->   PRIMARY KEY     (id)                                  # Make the id the primary key
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,14 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO cats ( name, owner, birth) VALUES
    ->   ( 'Sandy', 'Lennon', '2015-01-03' ),
    ->   ( 'Cookie', 'Casey', '2013-11-13' ),
    ->   ( 'Charlie', 'River', '2016-05-21' );
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0,07 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,07 sec)

mysql> GRANT RELOAD,PROCESS ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> RANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)
```

If DB is up and running then you write bad code, could you add parameters in MySqldb.connect() like here:

```
>>> db=MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='admin',passwd='password',db='Dance')
>>> cursor = db.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Dance.cats")
3L
>>> numrows = cursor.rowcount
>>> for x in range(0, numrows):
...     row = cursor.fetchone()
...     print row[0], "-->", row[1]
... 
1 --> Sandy
2 --> Cookie
3 --> Charlie
>>>
```

SRC:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python

Comment: @Melebius better?